# Android Beacon - displaying distance updates

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ibeacon-android

I want to display detected beacons in a recyclerview. So far, I've been able to avoid creating a new item once ranging updates are called but I can't get the distance value to be updated.

```
beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                final BeaconAdapter adapter = (BeaconAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter();

                for(Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                    if(!beaconList.contains(beacon)) {
                        beaconList.add(beacon);
                    }
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.clear();
                        adapter.addAll(beaconList);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This is the code I have in my BeaconAdapter

```
public void clear(){
    this.beaconList = null;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addAll(List<Beacon> beaconList){
    this.beaconList = beaconList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

How should I properly display the beacons so that I'm not getting redundant items but still able to obtain updates for the distance and other values?

Comment: Good question.  I am unsure how to force refresh of a RecyclerView when the elements change, but that is the core question here.  You may want to add other tag to attract an expert on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use:

```
yourAdapterName.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will refresh the list with the updated data.

Comment: thanks for answering, but I have already set these in my BeaconAdapter:

`public void clear(){
        this.beaconList = null;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addAll(List<Beacon> beaconList){
        this.beaconList = beaconList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

am I doing it right?

Comment: I think you are calling notifyDataSetChanged() only when you delete the whole data or when you add the add the data, and not when you receive a update about distance. You might want to check that.

Comment: I see, but if I pass the distance to the adapter, how would I know what specific item in the list I should update it to?

Comment: You do have the position in the OnBindHolder of your adapter, moreover notifyDataSetChanged() just refreshes all your items. See this definition of notifyDataSetChanged(): Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).